# Visual Studios for Mac: Unable to load the specified metadata resource

Tags: macos, visual-studio, entity-framework, metadata, edmx

In my C# Project I use Database First development using Entity Framework. The model is stored in an EDMX file (.edmx extension) in my project. This process automatically created a connection string as follows in my App.config:

```
<add name="TableEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DBModel.csdl|res://*/DBModel.ssdl|res://*/DBModel.msl ...
```

This project has been thoroughly tested on 'Visual Studios 2015 - Windows' and works flawlessly. Pulling the same repo in the 'Visual Studios for Mac' workspace throws a **System.Data.Entity.Core.MetadataException** with the following information:

---

Message: Unable to load the specified metadata resource.

Source: EntityFramework

TargetSite (Type - System.Reflection.MonoMethod):

> {System.Collections.Generic.List1
>   [System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataArtifactLoaderResource] LoadResources(System.String, System.String, System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[System.String], System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataArtifactAssemblyResolver)}

---

Do I need to alter my project in any way for this to work?

Has anyone managed to use Entity Framework with Visual Studios for Mac?

Comment: Did you find a solution ?

Comment: Unfortunately no. However you find a lot of alternatives on the Visual Studios for Mac - Nuget Manager to communicate with MSSQL.

Comment: I have fixed that by adding alternative nuget packages.. However, i face another problem now with SSL not supported for azure! But thanks anyway

Comment: That is a common issue I have faced many times. Usually its a result of using the wrong setup when binding the SSL. You just need to find the right setup.

Comment: I see. Thank you

Comment: @user4251864 what are the alternatives you have looked into?

Comment: 2 Years 1 month later, the problem still exists. Works on windows, but not on VS for Mac. Lord help us all, forever bound to windows.