# osx: Visual Studio Mac Unable to load the specified metadata resource

Tags: macos, visual-studio, entity-framework, metadata, edmx

I have a C# project running smoothly on Windows. Now, I am trying to run it on Visual Studio Mac.

Everything was going well until I tried some methods that connect with my database that uses EntityFramework. When executing the query, I am receiving the exception

`Unable to load the specified metadata resource.`

Any idea on how can I solve this? [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43500520/visual-studios-for-mac-unable-to-load-the-specified-metadata-resource) another dev was facing the same  situation and seems he/she resolved it using Nuget packages but do not mention which ones. Any help is greatly appreaciated.